# Can Flash/AS3 Filter instances be reused, and reapplied to display objects? They seem to fail unless I recreate the instance each time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, filter, shader

Is anyone aware of whether or not Filter instances in Flash can be reused?

I constructed a BevelFilter instance and assigned it to the filters array of a display object.

On rollover, I'm altering the existing BevelFilter instance's highlightColor and shadowColor properties to create a rollover effect and then reassigning it to the filter property (wrapped in an array of course).  When I reapply the filter in this way, it looks as though the blur effect is completely lost and it gets hard edges.

If I create a new BevelFilter instance with the new properties instead, then the effect is fine.

I've tried setting filters to an empty array before reassigning the filter, but that didn't work.  The only thing I haven't tried yet is setting filter to an empty array before modifying the existing BevelFilter instance, but I'm not sure that would make a difference.

I'm looking for some insight into this problem, such as why it's behaving this way and whether filters can be reused this way.

UPDATE: Asked to post code; ignore if not interested...

### Background

The "SkinnedButton" class I built supports a number of ways to create a button with seamless fallback to the most simple of implementations.  I supports a "skin" and "surface" (hit area) display objects, which separates the interaction layer from the visual layer.  These can be defined at design time or runtime.  The "surface" layer is raised above all other objects and has alpha set to 0, and functions as the hit area and event processor for the button.  The "skin" MovieClip supports frames labeled "default", "rollout", "rollover", "release", "press", "releaseoutside", "trackover", "trackout", "dragover", "dragout", "dragdrop", "selected", "rolloverselected", and "disabled".

A TrackedMouseEventHandler class handles all the logic for those events and states.  The skin fully supports chained fallback for missing states, so the button will still function with just a "default" state.  For example when the dragOut event occurs, there are two fallback chains depending on whether the button is selected:

```
private function dragOut( e:TrackedMouseEvent )
{
    state = DRAGOUT;
    if (_selected)
        reDispatch( e, SELECTED, DRAGOUT, ROLLOUT, RELEASEOUTSIDE, DEFAULT );
    else
        reDispatch( e, DRAGOUT, ROLLOUT, RELEASEOUTSIDE, DEFAULT ); //if "dragout" skin frame is present use that, else use "rollout", else use "releaseoutside", else use "default".
}
```

As an alternative to having a dedicated "selected" or "rolloverselected" frame on the skin, it also has a "selectedMask" and "focusMask" properties which will be made visible depending on whether the button is selected or has the focus.  It also supports boolean setting to determine whether the button is automatically selected on focus in and whether it's automatically deselected on focus out, allowing you to control how tightly coupled those two independent properties are.

In addition to the "skin", the button supports another construct for states so that you can leave "skin" null.  The other construct is for individual states to be assigned to their own display object instances named "mc_default", "mc_press", etc.  If these are present in the designer, they will automatically be aligned to the topleft of the button and their visibility will be set.  They can also be added at runtime, with the option to automatically add them to display list and align them, or not.  The auto-alignment allows you to lay out the states beside each other in the designer, and they will automatically be aligned and have their visibility set at runtime.

In addition to the "skin" and individual state clips -- as if those weren't sufficient options already -- the SkinnedButton also has an overridable method "stateChanged( out:Boolean, over:Boolean, down:Boolean )", which is what I'm using in this case to run the logic for a simple dynamic bevel effect.

### Relevant code:

```
//BevelFilter instance created once and updated/reused
//Blur values that are powers of 2 (e.g. 2,4,8,16) are optimized to render faster.  I rounded the blur up to 16 from 15 here.
private var bevel:BevelFilter = new BevelFilter( 5, 45, 0xffffff, 1, 0x000000, 1, 16, 16, 1, 2, BitmapFilterType.INNER, true );
public var mc_default:DisplayObject; //skin for "default" button state

//This code runs when the state changes, but the filter loses its blur
    override protected function stateChanging(out:Boolean, over:Boolean, down:Boolean):void 
    {
        //bevel = new BevelFilter( 5, 45, 0xffffff, 1, 0x000000, 1, 15, 15, 1, 2, BitmapFilterType.INNER, true ); //if I uncomment this, the problem goes away
        //mc_default.filters = []; //removing the filter before update has no effect
        if (over || down)
        {
            bevel.highlightColor = 0xffff33;
            bevel.shadowColor = 0xffff00;
            bevel.angle = down ? 190 : 45; //makes bevel appear depressed
        }
        else
        {
            bevel.highlightColor = 0xffffff;
            bevel.shadowColor = 0x000000;
            bevel.angle = 45; //makes bevel appear raised
        }
        //Reapply filter with updated properties
        //bevel.blurX = bevel.blurY = 16; //uncommenting this also fixes the problem; it seems that the blur values are lost unless explicitly reset before reassigning the filter, reguardless or whether the filter is actually changed at all
        mc_default.filters = [bevel]; //PROBLEM: bevel loses its blur somehow?  Tried setting filters=[] first, but no effect.
    }
```

Comment: Posted relevant code as well as some background information.

Comment: I've even worked with custom animated pixel bender shaders where I alter animated properties of the shader and they work fine.  I'm kind of wondering whether this is some kind of bug specific to the BevelFilter or an undocumented behavior.

Comment: Wow, nevermind, lol.  if (p = 1) should have been if (p == 1).  20 years of programming experience, and still able to make that mistake in a rush.  I just realized that the "popup" effect of the button is initially animated, and the animation termination condition was evaluating to true immediately, leaving the blur set at 0, which I didn't notice because I forgot to update the filter in the animation routine.  Terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I was setting the blur to zero elsewhere.  Filters can be reused without an issue.